# Как реализовать полузакрашенную цифру на css/svg?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, svg

Вот такая штука только на svg делается верно ? И как сделать плавное обтекание до половины, в свг слаб :)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Например:

```css
svg text {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-anchor: middle;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 70px;
  fill: url(#fendTestGrad);
}

#fendTestGrad .start {
  stop-color: #c2c5cc;
}
#fendTestGrad .end {
  stop-color: #8f98a1;
}

svg {
background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(73,85,97,1) 0%, rgba(74,88,101,1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="fendTestGrad" x1="52%" y1="52%" x2="48%" y2="48%">
        <animate 
          attributeName="x1" 
          from="0" to=".52"         
          dur="3s" 
          repeatCount="1">          
        </animate>
        <animate 
          attributeName="y1" 
          from="0" to=".52"         
          dur="3s" 
          repeatCount="1">          
        </animate>
        <animate 
          attributeName="x2" 
          from="0" to=".48"         
          dur="3s" 
          repeatCount="1">          
        </animate>
        <animate 
          attributeName="y2" 
          from="0" to=".48"         
          dur="3s" 
          repeatCount="1">          
        </animate>
      
      <stop class="start"></stop>
      <stop class="start"></stop>
      <stop class="end"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <text x="50%" y="70">60</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: То есть мне для эффекта анимации с offset нужно играться ?

Comment: @YourDeveloper, подправила теперь еще и с анимацией

Comment: @HamSter Здравствуйте! В задании были цифры с градиентом, в вашем решении(если выполнить здесь код) нет градиента. Минус поставил, возможно исправите.

Comment: @HamSter Леночка растешь в мастерстве прямо на глазах (+)

Comment: @Alexandr_T, смущаете)))

Comment: @HamSter, а как анимацию перенести в css? Хочу, через JS давать класс и будет включаться анимация.